# Is AKPlayer still available in AudioKit?

Tags: swift, audiokit

import AudioKit

but got error "Cannot find type 'AKPlayer' in scope." for below declaration:

var streamPlayer : AKPlayer?

version 5.6.1

Answer (score 0):

They dropped the AK prefix in AudioKit 5. The player class is now called AudioPlayer.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know that.